# Rendering <Context> directly is not supported and will be removed in a future major release error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

i am getting the following errror:

> Warning: Rendering  directly is not supported and will be removed in a future major release. Did you mean to render <Context.Consumer> instead?

This is my app.js component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import SignInSide from "./components/SignInSide";
import AboutUs from "./pages/AboutUs";
import ourservices from "./pages/OurServices";
import portfolio from "./pages/portfolio";
import SignUp from "./components/signup";
import booking from "./pages/book";
import PreviousBookings from "./pages/PreviousBookings";
import BookingContext from "./context/bookings/BookingContext";
function App() {
return (
<>
  <BookingContext>
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
        <Route path="/ourservices" component={ourservices} />
        <Route path="/developer" component={portfolio} />
        <Route path="/login" component={SignInSide} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        <Route path="/booking" component={booking} />
        <Route path="/booking-history" component={PreviousBookings} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </BookingContext>
</>
 );
 }

export default App;
```

I am trying to use the useContext hook.

Comment: Maybe you could show us your implementation of `BookingContext` ?

Comment: Definitely show us the BookingContext.js file. Also, if you aren't already, make sure you're using the context's provider, not just the raw context

Answer (score 12):

Solution for me was changing:

```
import AuthProvider from "./context/AuthContext";
```

To:

```
import {AuthProvider} from "./context/AuthContext";
```

I'm new with React, might be because AuthProvider is not the default export

Answer (score 4):

I had this error not too long ago. The issue was with my imports...so I was importing the context itself and rendering that, rather than the context provider function itself

Comment: I also made the same mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ei, I get also this error, this is my implementation if helps,

I commented `// const { Provider } = ProductContext;`

and change the `<Provider>` to `<ProductContext.Provider value={{}}>`.

```js
import { ReactElement, createContext } from 'react';

import { useProduct } from '../hooks/useProduct';
import { ProductContextProps,  Product } from '../interfaces/interfaces';

import styles from '../styles/styles.module.css'

export const ProductContext = createContext({} as ProductContextProps);
// const { Provider } = ProductContext;

export interface Props {
    product: Product;
    children?: ReactElement | ReactElement[];
    className?: string;
}

export const ProductCard = ({ children, product, className }: Props ) => {

    const { counter, increaseBy } = useProduct();

    return (
        <ProductContext.Provider value={{
            counter,
            increaseBy,
            product
        }}>
            <div className={ `${styles.productCard}   ${className}` }>
                { children }
            </div>
        </ProductContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the context in the test file like so:
`<DataContext> <Child /> </DataContext>`

Instead of:
`<DataProvider> <Child /> </DataProvider>`

Answer (score -1):

in my opinion, you need a file Context Provider ;

example :

```
"./BookingProvider"
function BookingProvider()
return (
 <BookingContext.Provider>
   ....
 <BookingContext.Provider>
)
 export default BookingProvide
"app.js"
<BookingProvide >
....
 </BookingProvide>
```